# expected string or bytes-like object while using RE to search in a list

Tags: python, regex, type-mismatch

I am using RE to search in a list but getting a type mis-match error which I am not able to figure out. This is the entire code.  I checked the type of r which come out as regex which I assume works with a string as I found that bit over here on stack overflow

```py
import re

i = int(input())
l = []
k = []

for j in range(i):

    l.append(int(input()))    

for a in l:

    n = int(a)

    hd = 0 
    ld = 9
    while n > 0:
        rn = n % 10
        if hd < rn:
            hd = rn
        if ld > rn:
            ld = rn
        n = int(n / 10)

    x = hd*11 + ld*7

    if x > 99:
        x = x - 100

    k.append(x)

cn = 0
r = re.compile("1[0-9]+")
nl = list(filter(r.search, k))
if len(nl) == 2 :
    cn = cn + 1
    type(r)
elif len(nl) > 2:
    cn = cn + 2
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-5ea828f5282e>", line 36, in <module>
    nl = list(filter(r.search, k))
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-13-5ea828f5282e>", line 36, in <module>
    nl = list(filter(r.search, k))
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: What's `k`? Presumably not a list of strings.

Comment: It is a list @tripleee

Comment: Then it's a list of something else than strings, obviously? You really should [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. Without sample data, we can't tell you anything which isn't already in the error message.

Comment: Show us exactly what it contains and how it is created.

Comment: I figured it out, I am sorry I took up your time, thank you and I would be more precise from the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, your list doesn't contain strings. You can convert a number to a string with `str(number)` and then do a regex match on the result, but in this case a simpler and more efficient filter would be to filter out numbers below 10. (I guess this will also allow you to drop the dependency on `re` entirely.)